# Using spreadsheet to count consecutive cells

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets, user-defined-functions

So I want to use Google spreadsheet to find how many times does five consecutive cells have a value greater than a given value in a row,but one cell cant be a part of two set of consecutive cells.For example i want to count the number of times a particular item was bought in a month for consecutive five days but if it was bought for 7 days at a stretch it will only be counted as one whereas if it is multiple of five it will be counted as many multiples of five.
For Ex:If cells 1-5 have a value greater than the given value it should give me a count of 1, but if cells 1-9 also are greater than the given value even then it should give me count of 1 but if 1-10 have a value greater than the given value then it should give me a count of 2.I hope this was clear.

I want to write this code in Google Drive using custom function, I tried writing a code in C.

*

```
int x; //no. of rows
int y; //no. of columns
int arr[x][y]; //array to store numbers
int count[x];
int i,j,k; //for loops
for(i=0;i<x;i++)  //set count to 0 for all rows
    count[x]=0;
for(i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        for(k=1;k<=5, j<y;k++, j++)
        {
            if(!arr[i][j]>0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(k==5 && arr[i][j]!<1)
                {
                                  count[i]++;
                                     j--;
                                 }
        }
    }
}
//display the count array now to see result.
```

*

Comment: C wont be of much use. apps script is javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without writing code. That's kinda the purpose of a spreadsheet.

You have one column, say column A, with the values.

In the next column, start a counter that increments each row if the value in the first column is >= your preset value, and reset the counter if not. The formula would be something like (for cell B2)

```
=IF(A2>=$E$1,B1+1,0)
```

In the next column, calculate the multiples of 5. For cell C2:

```
=IF(MOD(B2,5)=0,C1+1,C1)
```

Copy those cells down to the bottom of the list in column A, and the last value will be the count of values that exceeded cell $e1 a multiple of 5 consecutive times.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for replying but what I want to understand is that whether this will work without a loop??  I am very new to programming so am unable to solve this please help

Comment: Well, there are no loops in my answer, because there is no macro code involved. :) If you really must write code to solve this problem, then I don't see how you can do it without loop constructs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using native Sheets functions:

`=ArrayFormula((ROWS(A:A)-LEN(REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(LEFT(A:A>=1)),"TTTTT","")))/5)`

and using a custom function:

```
function countGroups(range, comparisonValue, groupSize) {
  var v = comparisonValue || 1; // default to comparing to 1 if not specified
  var n = groupSize || 5; // default to groups of 5 if not specified
  var count = 0, counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0, length = range.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (range[i][0] >= v) {
      counter++;
      if (counter == n) {
        counter = 0;
        count++;
      }
    }
    else
      counter = 0;
  }
  return count;
}
```